# creating multi signature address in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, multisignature

How can I create an array of multi-signature address (2-of-2 P2SH multisig, keeping one account on all the multi-signature account constant)  in web3js  or solidity so that my custom token can be transferred to all created account on creation? The token should be spent only after verification of both the account.

Answer (score 2):

creating multi-signature address in solidity

In terms of the user interface, the idea is that each multisig keyholder would have a UI where they enter in the details of the transaction they wish to send (ideally on an offline computer). Then on an online machine, an “operator” would gather up all the signatures from the keyholder and send off the actual transaction containing all the signatures. The operator would not need to have any actual control of funds, the multisig key holders are ultimately the ones that have the authority to execute transactions.

The complete code is presented here:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.14;
contract SimpleMultiSig {

  uint public nonce;                // (only) mutable state
  uint public threshold;            // immutable state
  mapping (address => bool) isOwner; // immutable state
  address[] public ownersArr;        // immutable state

  function SimpleMultiSig(uint threshold_, address[] owners_) {
    if (owners_.length > 10 || threshold_ > owners_.length || threshold_ == 0) {throw;}

    for (uint i=0; i<owners_.length; i++) {
      isOwner[owners_[i]] = true;
    }
    ownersArr = owners_;
    threshold = threshold_;
  }

  // Note that address recovered from signatures must be strictly increasing
  function execute(uint8[] sigV, bytes32[] sigR, bytes32[] sigS, address destination, uint value, bytes data) {
    if (sigR.length != threshold) {throw;}
    if (sigR.length != sigS.length || sigR.length != sigV.length) {throw;}

    // Follows ERC191 signature scheme: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/191
    bytes32 txHash = sha3(byte(0x19), byte(0), this, destination, value, data, nonce);

    address lastAdd = address(0); // cannot have address(0) as an owner
    for (uint i = 0; i < threshold; i++) {
        address recovered = ecrecover(txHash, sigV[i], sigR[i], sigS[i]);
        if (recovered <= lastAdd || !isOwner[recovered]) throw;
        lastAdd = recovered;
    }

    // If we make it here all signatures are accounted for
    nonce = nonce + 1;
    if (!destination.call.value(value)(data)) {throw;}
  }

  function () payable {}
}
```

code is also available this link [This github link](https://github.com/christianlundkvist/simple-multisig)

thank you

Comment: You just have copy paste parts of article https://medium.com/@ChrisLundkvist/exploring-simpler-ethereum-multisig-contracts-b71020c19037
It is worth to read whole and share a link.

Comment: yes but link provided @@@ Xawery Wiśniowiecki